# Saving image to device storage in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-intent, bitmap, imageview, storage

I have a bitmap of an ImageView and I want it to be downloaded to the device. I tried using this code:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},1);

FileOutputStream outStream = null;
File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File dir = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/MyFolder");
dir.mkdirs();
String fileName = String.format("%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis());
File outFile = new File(dir, fileName);
try {
    outStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outStream);
    outStream.flush();
    outStream.close();
} catch (IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
refreshGallery(outFile);
```

refreshGallery

```
 public void refreshGallery(File file){
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
        intent.setData(Uri.fromFile(file));
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
```

I get this error:
/storage/emulated/0/MyFolder/....jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

how can I fix it?

Comment: Most likely, you do not have permission. `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions()` is asynchronous. When it returns, you do not yet have permission. Also, none of this will work on Android 10 by default, as [you do not have access to arbitrary locations on external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/06/07/death-external-storage-end-saga.html). Perhaps you should switch to using `getExternalFilesDir()` on `Context` instead of `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`.

Comment: Using getExternalFilesDir() worked, Thank you!